# How do I specify gcc when compiling mod_perl

Tags: perl, gcc

I want to test if I have the correct compiler when compiling mod_perl. http://blogs.perl.org/users/neilb/2012/11/problems-building-mod-perl-on-mountain-lion-macosx-108.html.

How do you specify gcc instead of cc?

Currently running:

```
perl Makefile.PL MP_APXS=~/bin/apache2/bin/apxs MP_APR_CONFIG=~/bin/apache2/bin/apr-1-config
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only answer I have found is overwriting /usr/bin/cc with /usr/bin/gcc and putting cc back when I was finished.